# What would be a consistent estimator for the mean in this simple case of INID random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

Let there be a set of observations $\{Y_0, Y_1, \dots, Y_n \}$ from a stochastic process $\{ Y_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ where $Y_t \sim N( \theta^t \mu, 1)$, $Y_t$ is independent of $Y_s$ for all $s \ne t$ and $|\theta|<1, \mu \in \mathbb{R}$.  I would like to find an estimator for the mean of $Y_m$ that we will call $\mu_m$, where $m<n$ that is consistent.

If I utilize the maximum likelihood framework and aim to maximize the log likelihood

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^n\log \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} - \frac{1}{2}(Y_i - \theta^{-m+    i}\mu_m)^2
\end{align*}

I obtain  the maximum likelihood estimator is given by
$$ \hat{\mu}_m = \frac{Y_0 + Y_1 + \dots + Y_n}{\theta^{-m} + \theta^{-m+1}+ \dots+ \theta^{n-m}}$$
but it appears that denominator is finite as $n \rightarrow \infty$ so this estimator will not be consistent although it is unbiased. How would one find a consistent estimator for $\mu_m$? Is the maximum likelihood estimator salvageable in some way?

Any references to problems of this kind are also welcome.

Comment: I don't get why you have $\theta^{-m+    i}\mu_m$ and not just $\mu_i$. I feel like since the first part of the sum is a number, you have to maximize the latter, that since is negative you are looking for its minimum. But being a sum of squares the minimum is $Y_i = \mu_i$ for every $i$, am I wrong?

Comment: Since we are estimating the mean of a normal dist with one extraction, it should be obv that $\mu_i =Y_i$. The problem comes when you want to estimate the 2 parameters. I guess $\mu = Y_0$ is good, but with $\theta$ you have estimates for several powers of $\theta$... maybe a geometric mean of the $Y_i$ with the proper $k-th$ root $k=n(n+1)/2$? Just a random guess.